# C#: Triggering an Event when an object is added to a Queue

Tags: c#, events, delegates, queue

**I need to be able to trigger a event whenever an object is added to a `Queue<Delegate>`.**

I created a new class that extends `Queue`:

```
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public class QueueWithChange<Delegate> : Queue<Delegate>
{
    public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

    protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e) {
        if (Changed != null)
        {
            Changed(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And then attached the event from another class, like such:

```
QueueWithChange<TimerDelegate> eventQueue = new QueueWithChange<TimerDelegate>();

//

eventQueue.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs ex) {
    //This event is not being triggered, so this code is unreachable atm...and that is my problem

    if (eventQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        eventQueue.Dequeue().Invoke(new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5) });
        actionTimer.Stop();
    }
});
```

But whenever I enqueue an object (`eventQueue.Enqueue(something)`), the attached event is not being fired.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you mean the non-generic `Queue` class, then you can just override `Enqueue`:

```
public override void Enqueue(object obj)
{
    base.Enqueue(obj);
    OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

However, if you mean the generic `Queue<T>` class, then note that there is no suitable virtual method to override. You might do better to **encapsulate** the queue with your own class:

(** important edit: removed base-class!!! **)

```
class Foo<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    public event EventHandler Changed;
    protected virtual void OnChanged()
    {
        if (Changed != null) Changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public virtual void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(item);
        OnChanged();
    }
    public int Count { get { return queue.Count; } }

    public virtual T Dequeue()
    {
        T item = queue.Dequeue();
        OnChanged();
        return item;        
    }
}
```

However, looking at your code, it seems possible that you are using multiple threads here. If that is the case, consider a [threaded queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net) instead.

Comment: Excellent; This is Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks Marc for the quality answer.  And I will also check about the Threaded Queue you mentioned.

Comment: From a design principle perspective it is better to use composition over inheritance (broadly speaking) so I support your solution.

Comment: Marc, for what reason did you remove the base class ?

Comment: It was a mistake! I intended to use composition, not inheritance - since we've already observed that inheritance doesn't offer what we need...

Comment: +1 May I ask how to implement GetEnumerator() if it is possible at all ?

Comment: @adopilot `while(Count>0) yield return Dequeue();`

Comment: Starting in .NET 4.0, you can use the [ConcurrentQueue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a Thread Safe FIFO collection.

Answer (score 6):

I just did write up on what I call a TriggeredQueue. It's inspired the answer by Marc Gravell.

You can find my post here: [https://joesauve.com/triggeredqueuelttgt](https://www.joesauve.com/triggeredqueuelttgt/)

And the Gist here: [http://gist.github.com/jsauve/b2e8496172fdabd370c4](https://gist.github.com/jsauve/b2e8496172fdabd370c4)

It has four events:

- WillEnqueue
- WillDequeue
- DidEnqueue
- DidDequeue

You can hook into any of these like so:

```
YourQueue.WillEnqueue += (sender, e) => {
    // kick off some process
};
YourQueue.DidEnqueue += (sender, e) => {
    // kick off some process
    // e.Item provides access to the enqueued item, if you like
};
YourQueue.WillDequeue += (sender, e) => {
    // kick off some process
};
YourQueue.DidDequeue += (sender, e) => {
    // kick off some process
    // e.Item provides access to the dequeued item, if you like
};
```

One neat trick is that you can use the DidDequeue method to kick off some process to ensure that the queue is full by making a web request or loading some data from a filesystem, etc. I use this class in Xamarin mobile apps to ensure that data and images are pre-cached in order to provide a smooth user experience, instead of loading images AFTER they scroll onto the screen (like you might see in Facebook and countless other apps).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public new void Enqueue(Delegate d)
{
    base.Enqueue(d);
    OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: re-declaring / method-hiding is brittle, non-polymorphic, and brittle; the caller can skip your code simply with a cast.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override Enqueue, to call OnChanged.

Comment: Enqueue is not virtual on the generic Queue<T>

Comment: Right, that's a shame. I guess you'd have to create a IQueue interface and have your own implementation then.