# Constructor to allocate my own array<T> class

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a class like Quete (first in , first out)

```
public class Tor<T>
{
    private T[] elements;

    private int next;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> queueFull;   
}
```

I need to build a **Constructor** that get one parameter (queue size (int). and it allocate the arrary and initilizes the variable,

how to do it?

Comment: I guess you were a c++ programmer before:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simple

```
public Tor(int size)
{
  elements = new T[size];
}
```

Comment: From question `allocate the arrary and initilizes the variable`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Tor<T> where T : new()
{
    public Tor(int size)
    { 
        elements = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            elements[i] = new T();
        }
    }

    private T[] elements;

    private int next;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> queueFull;   
}
```

or

```
public class Tor<T> where T : new()
{
    public Tor(int size)
    { 
        elements = Enumerable.Range(1,size).Select (e => new T()).ToArray(); 
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Tor<T>
{
    private T[] elements;

    private int next;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> queueFull;

    public Tor(int capacity)
    {
        elements = new T[capacity];
    }
}
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Tor<T>
{
    private T[] elements;

    private int next;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> queueFull;

    public Tor(int size)
    {
        if (size < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Size cannot be less then zero");

        elements = new T[size];
        next = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using existing classes

- derive from Queue if needed events like suggested in [C#: Triggering an Event when an object is added to a Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531438/c-triggering-an-event-when-an-object-is-added-to-a-queue)
- or if you want to build your own use List which will allow to grow array as needed/preallocate if you want to.