# In C#, is there a queue which can only hold an object once in its lifetime?

Tags: c#, data-structures, queue

I need a datastructure, which is a special type of queue. I want that, if an instance of my queue ever contained an object X, it shouldn't be possible to enqueue X again in this instance. The enqueuing method should just do nothing if called with X, like the attempt to add a duplicate value to a HashSet.

Example usage:

```
MyQueue<int> queue = new MyQueue<int>(); 
queue.Enqueue(5); 
queue.Enqueue(17); 
queue.Enqueue(28); 
queue.Enqueue(17); 
int firstNumber = queue.Dequeue(); 
queue.Enqueue(5); 
queue.Enqueue(3); 

List<int> queueContents = queue.ToList(); //this list should contain {17, 28, 3}
```

I looked around on MSDN, but couldn't find such a class. Does it exist, or do I have to implement it myself?

I guess I could use a different data structure too, but access will always be FIFO, so I thought a queue will be most efficient. Also, I don't know of any other structure which provides such "uniqueness over instance lifetime" feature.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to roll out your own.

Comment: Possible it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-sharp-set-collection

Comment: @Eugene OP already mentioned HashSet in the question.

Comment: @Eugene If I remove an element from a HashSet, I can add it again later. I want a structure which doesn't allow me to do that. Like a HashSet with a memory and element order.

Comment: Note, for this to work correctly whatever type you are passing in to the queue must support a proper comparisons for equality (`.Equals(object)` and `.GetHashCode()`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something similar to this:

```
class UniqueQueue<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    private HashSet<T> alreadyAdded = new HashSet<T>();

    public virtual void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        if (alreadyAdded.Add(item)) { queue.Enqueue(item); }
    }
    public int Count { get { return queue.Count; } }

    public virtual T Dequeue()
    {
        T item = queue.Dequeue();
        return item;
    }
}
```

Note, most of this code was borrowed from [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531438/c-triggering-an-event-when-an-object-is-added-to-a-queue).

Comment: You should be using a `HashSet` instead of a `List` here.  A list will perform much worse.

Comment: I would agree, after reading the other answers.  Unfortunately never used a HashSet before so I wasn't aware of it.  Infact I wish I could upvote some of the other answers.

Comment: Of course, was just making sure I understood the benefits of HashSet's before I publicly agreed they were better.

Comment: Rather than `if (alreadyAdded.Contains(item)) return;` do `if (alreadyAdded.Add(item)) { queue.Enqueue(item); }`. `Add` returns `true` if the item was added. It returns `false` if the item already exists. Basically, you're saving a lookup and simplifying your code.

Comment: `Dequeue` should clear the dequeued item out of `alreadyAdded`, otherwise subsequent calls to `Enqueue` won't work.

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to implement that yourself.

One idea is just to add the element to a `HashSet` when you enqueue it.

Then, when you want to enqueue, just check the `HashSet` for the item, if it exists, don't enqueue.

Since you want to prevent enqueuing for the rest of the queue's lifetime, you probably won't want to ever remove from the `HashSet`.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a extended version of [wayne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19956468/80274), it is just a little more fleshed out and having a few more interfaces supported. (To mimic `Queue<T>`'s interfaces)

```
sealed class UniqueQueue<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable
{
    private readonly Queue<T> queue;
    private readonly HashSet<T> alreadyAdded;

    public UniqueQueue(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        queue = new Queue<T>();
        alreadyAdded = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    }

    public UniqueQueue(IEnumerable<T> collection, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        //Do this so the enumeration does not happen twice in case the enumerator behaves differently each enumeration.
        var localCopy = collection.ToList();

        queue = new Queue<T>(localCopy);
        alreadyAdded = new HashSet<T>(localCopy, comparer);
    }

    public UniqueQueue(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        queue = new Queue<T>(capacity);
        alreadyAdded = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    }

    //Here are the constructors that use the default comparer. By passing null in for the comparer it will just use the default one for the type.
    public UniqueQueue() : this((IEqualityComparer<T>) null) { }
    public UniqueQueue(IEnumerable<T> collection) : this(collection, null) { }
    public UniqueQueue(int capacity) : this(capacity, null) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to enqueue a object, returns false if the object was ever added to the queue in the past.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to enqueue</param>
    /// <returns>True if the object was successfully added, false if it was not</returns>
    public bool Enqueue(T item)
    {
        if (!alreadyAdded.Add(item))
            return false;

        queue.Enqueue(item);
        return true;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return queue.Count; }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        return queue.Dequeue();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)queue).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)queue).GetEnumerator();
    }

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        ((ICollection)queue).CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return ((ICollection)queue).IsSynchronized; }
    }

    object ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get { return ((ICollection)queue).SyncRoot; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I ended up implementing. I forgot to include the implementation of all the constructors and the ICollection interface (although I thought of IEnumerable), but implemented queue-specific methods you don't include, such as Peek. But I hope you don't mind me giving the accepted answer to wayne, because he was first and also because he can use the reputation, this being his first post.

Comment: @RumiP. Give Wayne the credit, I just wanted to give a fuller implementation for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a basic queue, but modify the Enqueue method to verify the previous values entered. Here, I used a hashset to contain those previous values :

```
public class UniqueValueQueue<T> : Queue<T>
{
    private readonly HashSet<T> pastValues = new HashSet<T>();

    public new void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        if (!pastValues.Contains(item))
        {
            pastValues.Add(item);

            base.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }
}
```

With your test case

```
UniqueValueQueue<int> queue = new UniqueValueQueue<int>();
queue.Enqueue(5);
queue.Enqueue(17);
queue.Enqueue(28);
queue.Enqueue(17);
int firstNumber = queue.Dequeue();
queue.Enqueue(5);
queue.Enqueue(3);

List<int> queueContents = queue.ToList();
```

queueContents contains 17, 28 and 3.

Comment: You don't need a HashSet. You could just call Contains(item) from Queue<T> to check whether the item already exists.

Comment: The problem is that since `Enqueue` isn't virtual you have the possibility of someone casting the object to `Queue` and adding duplicates.  It's likely best to not inherit from queue but encapsulate it.

Comment: @Kabbalah That would perform much, much worse, as searching through a hashset is much faster than searching through a queue.  On top of that. the requirements are that you shouldn't be able to add an item that was ever in the queue, not just items currently in the queue.

Comment: @Kabbalah No, try it with OP's test case and you'll see it fails. Can't add any item that ever been enqueued, not only currently queued items.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Sorry I missed that. I've deleted my answer.