# C# Multithreading issue with Monitor-class - possible lifelock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock, monitor

I have a bit of code, which I can't figure out properly. The problem is that the program is multithreaded and within there is a bit of code that should be synchronized so I wrote this:

```
lock (lockObject)
{
   if (!Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
     Monitor.Wait(lockObject);

   //do stuff...
   Monitor.PulseAll(lockObject);
}
Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
```

the problem I've got is that in some point in time all Threads seem to be sleeping - can someone tell why? The program keeps running along endlessly consuming nearly no cpu but no work is done - when tracing the program I found out that on some point no thread is active but a whole lot of them is sleeping. I know the error mostly (in case of a developer - always) sits 0.5m in front of the monitor - but I cannot figure it out myself... maybe in a few minutes ;)

can someone please explain that to me - thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the LockObject you are locking the same one your are doing a Monitor.TryEnter on, or are you locking the type LockObject?

Comment: yes - that was a classic typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a difference between `LockObject` and `lockObject`? It isn't clear...

However! If they are different objects, then first: you can't `Wait` on a lock that you don't have... and `TryEnter` will only return false if you specify a timeout. What exactly is that code trying to do?

Without more context, it isn't entirely clear what the `PulseAll` and `Wait` are designed to do; for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228) they are used to block the queue when it is too full (`Wait`), or release it when space becomes available (`PulseAll`), etc. It is hard to debug threading code without the full interactions between threads.

It sounds like you might just need:

```
lock (lockObject)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

---

There are two immediate problems I can see; first, it isn't obvious that you always release the locks you take (i.e. exceptions). Try to just use `lock` for the `Enter/Exit` - it'll get it right.

Second; if all the threads call `Wait`... who is going to wake them up? What are they waiting **for**? As presented: yes, they will all sleep indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assming the first lock statement is a typo and you meant lock(lockObject) (lowercase).

I think you're misunderstanding locks a bit here.  The if block in your code won't ever be true.  The reason why is that lock(lockObject) actually exapands to the following

```
Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
try {
...
} finally{ 
Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
```

So by the time you hit the if block you already own the lock and TryEnter should always succeed.

Comment: Give or take a variable ;-p For info, it looks like this pattern is changing in C# 4.0: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx

Comment: @Marc, yes it's very exciting to see this change.

Answer (score 1):

That is a strange setup.  Is 'LockObject' the same as 'lockObject'?  Or is that a typo?  If they are the same, then your setup is redundant, as there is no need to call Monitor.TryEnter on something you are already locking.  If 'LockObject' is a different object, then why not move the Monitor.Exit to inside the lock statement?