# Thread-safe async byte queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5, queue, producer-consumer

I've got a callback method that is called whenever new data is available:

```
public delegate void DataCallback(
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int count);
```

I want to wrap this in a class that implements an interface similar to this:

```
public interface IDataSource
{
    IAsyncResult BeginRead(
        byte[] buffer,
        int offset,
        int size,
        TimeSpan timeout,
        AsyncCallback callback,
        object state);

    int EndRead(
        IAsyncResult asyncResult);

    int Read(
        byte[] buffer,
        int offset,
        int size,
        TimeSpan timeout);
}
```

This is obviously a classical producer-consumer problem: the bytes are produced by calls to the callback method, and consumed by the Begin/EndRead and Read methods. The Begin/EndRead and Read methods should block if no data is available (until a timeout occurs). The implementation should use a fixed-size internal buffer, so the callback method needs to block when the buffer is currently full.

Since thinking about multithreading usually results in a severe headache, my question is: **Is there already an implementation of such a data structure?**

(I think implementing the Read method should be quite simple, but I'd like to avoid implementing Begin/EndRead with Read.`Begin`/`EndInvoke`.)

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be async via `IAsyncResult`? I have a generic *blocking* queue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228) (i.e. readers block until there is data or it is closed; writers block until there is space); it isn't optimised specifically for `byte[]`, but as long as the size isn't vast it should cope - but as a blocking queue it requires (at least one) dedicated consumer thread, doing:

```
T val;
while(queue.TryDequeue(out val)) {
    // process val
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, and I think it should be possible to modify this to be optimized for byte[]. Unfortunately the interface requires me to implement the Begin/EndRead methods as well...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a google search on "lockless queue". I got lots of usefull hits that way.