# possible factors in slowing down a parallel program

Tags: parallel-processing, cpu

Consider a program that can be run in parallel and is moved from a single core to a quad core.
Will the speed up be 4-fold?

Say you do not see the expected speedup in the program. What can be the possible reasons? Cache is one reason if each core does not have a separate cache then we have a problem. What could be the other issues?

Comment: Most generally, you won't get the expected speedup if the different cores are waiting on a shared resource (I/O bus...). Often this is memory, but it could be "any other resource". What kinds of things is your code doing? Do you have an example?

Comment: This was just  conversation I was having with someone.Say if you have a program that can most certainly be dedicated to separate cores, then you must expect a certain speedup when done in multiple cores. What could be the possible conceptual reasons of this not happening

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason you could not see a performance boost is if the work you're dividing over four processors is really small. If you have 4 simple addition operations that you're sending to separate processors, it might take more time to do the work of delegation than to just do the 4 operations on one processor.

Comment: Got it.This makes sense. Can you think of any other reasons?

Comment: I like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520837/what-are-common-concurrency-pitfalls). And the third answer on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937616/what-are-some-common-pitfalls-developers-run-into-with-multi-threading). And I actually just came from a lecture that was all about the pitfalls of multithreading. Would be happy to share it with you once the slides become available.