# C# : Monitor - Wait,Pulse,PulseAll 

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am having hard time in understanding  `Wait()`, `Pulse()`, `PulseAll()`. Will all of them avoid deadlock? I would appreciate if you explain how to use them?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Short version:

```
lock(obj) {...}
```

is short-hand for `Monitor.Enter` / `Monitor.Exit` (with exception handling etc). If nobody else has the lock, you can get it (and run your code) - otherwise your thread is blocked until the lock is aquired (by another thread releasing it).

Deadlock typically happens when either A: two threads lock things in different orders:

```
thread 1: lock(objA) { lock (objB) { ... } }
thread 2: lock(objB) { lock (objA) { ... } }
```

(here, if they each acquire the first lock, neither can *ever* get the second, since neither thread can exit to release their lock)

This scenario can be minimised by always locking in the same order; and you can recover (to a degree) by using `Monitor.TryEnter` (instead of `Monitor.Enter`/`lock`) and specifying a timeout.

or B: you can block yourself with things like winforms when thread-switching while holding a lock:

```
lock(obj) { // on worker
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { // switch to UI
        lock(obj) { // oopsiee!
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

The deadlock appears obvious above, but it isn't so obvious when you have spaghetti code; possible answers: don't thread-switch while holding locks, or use `BeginInvoke` so that you can at least exit the lock (letting the UI play).

---

`Wait`/`Pulse`/`PulseAll` are different; they are for signalling. I use this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228) to signal so that:

- `Dequeue`: if you try to dequeue data when the queue is empty, it waits for another thread to add data, which wakes up the blocked thread
- `Enqueue`: if you try and enqueue data when the queue is full, it waits for another thread to remove data, which wakes up the blocked thread

`Pulse` only wakes up *one* thread - but I'm not brainy enough to prove that the next thread is always the one I want, so I tend to use `PulseAll`, and simply re-verify the conditions before continuing; as an example:

```
        while (queue.Count >= maxSize)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(queue);
        }
```

With this approach, I can safely add other meanings of `Pulse`, without my existing code assuming that "I woke up, therefore there is data" - which is handy when (in the same example) I later needed to add a `Close()` method.

Answer (score 47):

Simple recipe for use of Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse. It consists of a worker, a boss, and a phone they use to communicate:

```
object phone = new object();
```

A "Worker" thread:

```
lock(phone) // Sort of "Turn the phone on while at work"
{
    while(true)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(phone); // Wait for a signal from the boss
        DoWork();
        Monitor.PulseAll(phone); // Signal boss we are done
    }
}
```

A "Boss" thread:

```
PrepareWork();
lock(phone) // Grab the phone when I have something ready for the worker
{
    Monitor.PulseAll(phone); // Signal worker there is work to do
    Monitor.Wait(phone); // Wait for the work to be done
}
```

More complex examples follow...

A "Worker with something else to do":

```
lock(phone)
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(Monitor.Wait(phone,1000)) // Wait for one second at most
        {
            DoWork();
            Monitor.PulseAll(phone); // Signal boss we are done
        }
        else
            DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

An "Impatient Boss":

```
PrepareWork();
lock(phone)
{
    Monitor.PulseAll(phone); // Signal worker there is work to do
    if(Monitor.Wait(phone,1000)) // Wait for one second at most
        Console.Writeline("Good work!");
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. How is it possible that Boss and Worker are in "phone" lock at the same time?

Comment: @Marshall Monitor.Wait releases "phone" lock to the next in line (presumably to the Boss).

Comment: @DennisGorelik ahh, I see. I have expanded your point [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42581381/1282864)

Comment: Thanks for the analogy - it was really helpful.

Comment: Your first example can deadlock. Let's say boss acquired the lock first, sends pulse to all waiting  threads (nobody at this point) then releases lock and waits to reacquire (Monitor.Wait). A worker grabs the lock, and releases it waiting for pulse which will never come. When the worker released this lock, note boss cannot re acquire it since no pulse was sent. For anyone to acquire lock they have to be in ready queue. To get from wait queue to ready queue someone needs to send a pulse.

Answer (score 12):

No, they don't protect you from deadlocks. They are just more flexible tools for thread synchronization. Here is a very good explanation how to use them and very important pattern of usage - without this pattern you will break all the things:
http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

Comment: FOR NOVICES HIGHLY RECOMMEND the albahari page is perfect! Goes through threading and syncing step by step with clear examples.

Answer (score 2):

Something that total threw me here is that `Pulse` just gives a "heads up" to a thread in a `Wait`. The Waiting thread will not continue until the thread that did the `Pulse` *gives up the lock* and the waiting thread successfully wins it.

```
lock(phone) // Grab the phone
{
    Monitor.PulseAll(phone); // Signal worker
    Monitor.Wait(phone); // ****** The lock on phone has been given up! ******
}
```

or

```
lock(phone) // Grab the phone when I have something ready for the worker
{
    Monitor.PulseAll(phone); // Signal worker there is work to do
    DoMoreWork();
} // ****** The lock on phone has been given up! ******
```

In both cases it's not until "the lock on phone has been given up" that another thread can get it.

There might be other threads waiting for that lock from `Monitor.Wait(phone)` or `lock(phone)`. Only the one that wins the lock will get to continue.

Answer (score 1):

They are tools for synchronizing and signaling between threads. As such they do nothing to prevent deadlocks, but if used correctly they can be used to synchronize and communicate between threads.

Unfortunately most of the work needed to write correct multithreaded code is currently the developers' responsibility in C# (and many other languages). Take a look at how F#, Haskell and Clojure handles this for an entirely different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, *none* of Wait(), Pulse() or PulseAll() have the magical property which you are wishing for - which is that by using *this* API you will automatically avoid deadlock.

Consider the following code

```
object incomingMessages = new object(); //signal object

LoopOnMessages()
{
    lock(incomingMessages)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(incomingMessages);
    }
    if (canGrabMessage()) handleMessage();
    // loop
}

ReceiveMessagesAndSignalWaiters()
{
    awaitMessages();
    copyMessagesToReadyArea();
    lock(incomingMessages) {
        Monitor.PulseAll(incomingMessages); //or Monitor.Pulse
    }
    awaitReadyAreaHasFreeSpace();
}
```

This code will deadlock! Maybe not today, maybe not tomorrow. Most likely when your code is placed under stress because suddenly it has become popular or important, and you are being called to fix an urgent issue.

Why?

Eventually the following will happen:

1. All consumer threads are doing some work
2. Messages arrive, the ready area can't hold any more messages, and PulseAll() is called.
3. *No consumer gets woken up, because none are waiting*
4. All consumer threads call Wait() [DEADLOCK]

This particular example assumes that producer thread is never going to call PulseAll() again because it has no more space to put messages in. But there are *many, many* broken variations on this code possible. People will try to make it more robust by changing a line such as making `Monitor.Wait();` into

```
if (!canGrabMessage()) Monitor.Wait(incomingMessages);
```

Unfortunately, that still isn't enough to fix it. To fix it you *also* need to change the locking scope where `Monitor.PulseAll()` is called:

```
LoopOnMessages()
{
    lock(incomingMessages)
    {
        if (!canGrabMessage()) Monitor.Wait(incomingMessages);
    }
    if (canGrabMessage()) handleMessage();
    // loop
}

ReceiveMessagesAndSignalWaiters()
{
    awaitMessagesArrive();
    lock(incomingMessages)
    {
        copyMessagesToReadyArea();
        Monitor.PulseAll(incomingMessages); //or Monitor.Pulse
    }
    awaitReadyAreaHasFreeSpace();
}
```

The key point is that in the fixed code, the locks restrict the possible sequences of events:

1. A consumer threads does its work and loops
2. That thread acquires the lock

   And thanks to locking it is now true that *either*:
3. a. Messages *haven't yet* arrived in the ready area, and it releases the lock by calling Wait() BEFORE the message receiver thread can acquire the lock and copy more messages into the ready area, *or*

   b. Messages have *already arrived* in the ready area and it receives the messages INSTEAD OF calling Wait(). (And while it is making this decision it is impossible for the message receiver thread to e.g. acquire the lock and copy more messages into the ready area.)

As a result the problem of the original code now never occurs:
 3. When PulseEvent() is called *No consumer gets woken up, because none are waiting*

Now observe that in this code you *have to get the locking scope exactly right*. (If, indeed I got it right!)

And also, since you must use the `lock` (or `Monitor.Enter()` etc.) in order to use `Monitor.PulseAll()` or `Monitor.Wait()` in a deadlock-free fashion, you still have to worry about possibility of *other* deadlocks which happen because of that locking.

**Bottom line: these APIs are also easy to screw up and deadlock with, i.e. quite dangerous**

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example of monitor use :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int[] X = new int[30];
        static readonly object _object = new object();
        public static int count=0;
        public static void PutNumbers(int numbersS, int numbersE)
        {

            for (int i = numbersS; i < numbersE; i++)
            {
                Monitor.Enter(_object);
                try
                {
                    if(count<30)
                    {
                        X[count] = i;
                        count++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Punt in " + count + "nd: "+i);
                        Monitor.Pulse(_object); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(_object);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(_object);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void RemoveNumbers(int numbersS)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < numbersS; i++)
            {
                Monitor.Enter(_object);
                try
                {
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        X[count] = 0;
                        int x = count;
                        count--;
                        Console.WriteLine("Removed " + x + " element");
                        Monitor.Pulse(_object);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(_object);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(_object);
                }
            }
        }



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread W1 = new Thread(() => PutNumbers(10,50));
            Thread W2 = new Thread(() => PutNumbers(1, 10));
            Thread R1 = new Thread(() => RemoveNumbers(30));
            Thread R2 = new Thread(() => RemoveNumbers(20));
            W1.Start();
            R1.Start();
            W2.Start();
            R2.Start();
            W1.Join();
            R1.Join();
            W2.Join();
            R2.Join();
        }
    }
}
```