# Clearing the ThreadPool

Tags: c#, threadpool

I'm working on my first ThreadPool application in Visual Studio 2008 with C#.

I have a report that has to perform calculations on 2000 to 4000 parts using data on our SQL Server.

I am Queuing all of the part numbers in a ThreadPool, where they go off and calculate their results. When these threads are finished, the RegisterWaitForSingleObject event fires to Unregister the Queued Item's Handle.

After all of the Queued Items have finished, is there a way to remove them from the ThreadPool?

The way it looks, if someone runs another report using a new set of 2000 to 4000 parts, I have no way of removing the previous array of parts.

How would I remove the Previously Queued Items? Would calling SetMaxThreads with workerThreads = 0 do it?

I realize I could experiment, but then I could waste most of the week experimenting.

Thanks for your time,
Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a `ThreadPool` item completes, it is automatically removed from the queue. What is indicating to you that they aren't?

Comment: Nothing indicates they are not ...but at the same time, nothing indicates they are! I wasn't able to find any documentation that said old items entered into the Queue were *ever* released.

Thanks for your answer!  
Joe

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean to interrupt (cancel) the work on the current queue...

Changing the max-threads won't affect the pending work; it'll just change the number of threads available to do it - and it is generally a bad idea to mess with this (your code isn't the only thing using the `ThreadPool`). I would use a custom queue - it is fairly easy to write a basic (thread-safe) producer/consumer queue, or .NET 4.0 includes some very good custom thread queues.

Then you can just abort the custom queue and start a new one.

I wrote a simple one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228); at the moment it wants to exit cleanly (i.e. drain the queue until it is empty) before terminating, but it would be easy enough to add a flag to stop immediately after the current item (don't resort to interrupting/aborting threads at an arbitrary point in execution; never a good idea).

Comment: Thanks for the help, Mr. Gravell. I will say that I *have* already run GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads), doubled both values, and then tested saving them with the call to ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(workerThreads, completionPortThreads).  How long is that setting going to remain active, just while the parent process is active, until I reboot, or until I call SetMaxThreads again with another value?

Comment: Per process or until you change it again, I suspect.