# Thread Synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a list of objects,
    for each object i want to run a totally separate thread (thread safty),like....i will pick one a object from my list in while loop and run a thread and then for next object run the next threads...all thread should be synchronized such that resources (values/connection (close/open) )shared by them should not change.....

Answer (score 2):

Starting a thread *per object* is not necessarily wise; you should probably have a small number of worker threads picking items off the list (or better, a `Queue<T>`), synchronizing access to that list/queue. An example of a thread-safe queue can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net).

Once you *have* a work item, there is no magic bullet for making the rest of the code you write (to process it) thread-safe. A sensible approach that keeps things simple is immutability - either true immutability (the items **can't** change), or simply **don't change the object**. You can of course implement locking around the work item, but this only helps if **all** your code uses the same locking strategy, which is hard to enforce.

Answer (score 0):

> i will pick one a object from my list
>   in while loop and run a thread and
>   then for next object run the next
>   threads

If I really wanted a thread per object, which I probably wouldn't, I would create a class like this:

```
class ObjectProcessingThread
{
Thread processingThread = new Thread();
public TargetObject { get; set;}

public Start()
{
    //start the processing thread with threadEntryPoint as the work the thread will do
} 

private threadEntryPoint
{
   //do stuff with targetObject
}
}
```

Then in the while loop new up an ObjectProcessingThread for each object, setting it's TargetObject property, then calling Start.

> all thread should be synchronized such
>   that resources (values/connection
>   (close/open) )shared by them should
>   not change.....

If you don't want values to change, don't change them.