# C# Is it possible to interrupt a specific thread inside a ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, interrupt

Suppose that I've queued a work item in a `ThreadPool`, but the work item blocks if there is no data to process (reading from a `BlockingQueue`).  If the queue is empty and there will be no more work going into the queue, then I must call the `Thread.Interrupt` method if I want to interrupt the blocking task, but how does one do the same thing with a `ThreadPool`?

The code might look like this:

```
void Run()
{
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            blockingQueue.Dequeue();
            doSomething();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        countDownLatch.Signal();
    }
}
```

I'm aware that the best thing to do in this situation is use a regular `Thread`, but I'm wondering if there is a `ThreadPool` equivalent way to interrupt a work item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which `BlockingQueue` is that? Is that a BCL class? TPL class? Or custom?

No matter; simply - I wouldn't. You *could* do something early in the thread's life to store the thread reference, but I simply wouldn't use the `ThreadPool` for this job as it sounds like it is longer running. A regular `Thread` would seem more appropriate.

I'm also surprised that there is no inbuilt method of telling the queue to release all the workers - I've written blocking queues before, and I tend to use the pattern (for example, [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228)):

```
public bool TryDequeue(out T value) {...}
```

with this:

- returning true immediately if there is data
- blocking and (eventually) returning true if there isn't data but some is added
- blocking and (eventually) returning false if the queue is being shut down

Comment: A non-volatile boolean variable (closing) tested in a short loop, does that always work?

Comment: @nobugz - I *believe* the `Monitor.Wait` will force a refresh; interesting question though.

Comment: Lock statement: yes, due to try block.  Monitor.Wait(), very doubtful. It would require the JIT to detect specific methods.

Comment: @nobugz note that `Wait` calls into `ObjWait` which is `internalcall`, so it isn't entirely up to the JIT; but I might throw this open as a question.

Comment: @nobugz - raised here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431238/does-monitor-wait-ensure-that-fields-are-re-read