# Fast and Best Producer/consumer queue technique BlockingCollection vs concurrent Queue

Tags: concurrency, c#-3.0, consumer, producer

Im using Generic.Queue in C# 3.0 and Monitor.Enter,wait,exit for wait before consuming the queue (wait for the element to be enqueued). Now im moving to C# 4.

Can anyone suggest me which one is fast and best especially to avoid locks..

BlockingCollection vs concurrentQueue or any thing else...

Note. I dont want to restrict my producer

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 118, accepted):

[`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) and [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) are there for precisely this reason. I doubt that you'll find anything better, or simpler to use. The parallel extensions team know their stuff :)

Just a quick check on versions though - you're definitely using .NET 4, not just C# 4? (For example, you could be using Visual Studio 2010 and thus C# 4, but still targeting .NET 3.5, in which case you couldn't use Parallel Extensions.)

You may also want to start researching [Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=204847), [TPL Dataflow](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=205053) and the [async/await features of C# 5](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=204845)... obviously you can't use them just yet, but it doesn't hurt to know what's coming up.

Comment: BlockingCollection and ConcurrentQueue which one is fast and best

Comment: @MSK: You create a `ConcurrentQueue` and then wrap it in a `BlockingCollection` which coordinates the Add/Take methods. (You then let it manage the queue completely - you shouldn't touch the ConcurrentQueue directly yourself afterwards.)

Comment: Thank u.. Pls suggest me BlockingCollection/ConcurrentQueue which one is fast and best

Comment: @MSK: Did you actually *read* my comment? *You use the two types together.* Create a `ConcurrentQueue`, and then create a `BlockingCollection` to wrap it. Then use the `BlockingCollection` exclusively. (In fact, if you just create a BlockingCollection without passing anything to the constructor, it will create a ConcurrentQueue for you, but you ought to understand what's going on.)

Comment: @MSK: I don't know what more to tell you really... I've told you how to do it twice. Have you read the docs for BlockingCollection, and the example in there?

Comment: @jon : BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>();
           
            Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                bc.Add(1);
                bc.Add(2);
                bc.Add(3);
                bc.CompleteAdding();
            });

           
            Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {                   
                    while (true) Console.WriteLine(bc.Take());
                }          
                }
            });

Comment: @ jon :In the above code, Will the Take() waits if the queue is empty and resumes to dequeue autmatically if new item is added (without using wait/signal). Or i have ot use monitor.wai,pulseall / ManualResetEvent ?

Comment: @MSK: What does the documentation for BlockingCollection.Take say? (You might also want to look at BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()).

Comment: @jon :  Takes an item from the BlockingCollection<T>. A call to Take may block until an item is available to be removed.

Comment: @MSK: Exactly. So if the queue is empty, it will block until there's an item in the queue. The whole point of using the type is to avoid you having to use Wait etc.

Comment: @jon : I had a little bit of confusion that will it resumes or not. Thats why the repetition in my Question. K . Now im Clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One point about ConcurrentQueue that I've just run into with a Pro/Con implementation... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/05/08/concurrentqueue-lt-t-gt-holding-on-to-a-few-dequeued-elements.aspx No biggie if the items are small... a significant problem if they are large objects (like mine are)

Comment: I would +10 this post if I could, I really mean it! BTW, a `BlockingCollection` can be iterated using a `Parallel.For`, which is similar in utility to a PCQ, and possibly a bit easier (maybe a LOT easier) to whip up the code for.

Comment: BlockingCollection wraps ConcurrentQueue by default - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx