# Why CancellationTokenRegistration exists and why does it implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, idisposable, cancellation-token

I've been seeing code that uses `Cancellation.Register` with a `using` clause on the `CancellationTokenRegistration` result:

```
using (CancellationTokenRegistration ctr = token.Register(() => wc.CancelAsync()))
{
    await wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.hamster.com"));
}
```

I get that you should make sure you `Dispose` an `IDisposable`, but why does it even implements `IDisposable`? what resources does it have to release? The only methods it has regard equality.

What happens if you don't `Dispose` of it? what do you leak?

Comment: It is dispose abuse, it should have an Unregister() method instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: Whether it's "abuse" or not depends upon whether one views `IDisposable.Dispose` as existing for the purpose of cleaning up resources, or for the purpose of ensuring that something which needs to get done, gets done (resource cleanup is the dominant type of "necessary action", but not the only one).

Comment: @HansPassant - It's also used heavily in asp.net MVC.  I don't think it's abuse if the framework authors do it themselves.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This pattern is a convenient way to make sure `CancellationTokenRegistration.Unregister()` is called automatically. It's often used by Stephen Toub in his [Parallel Programming with .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/) blog posts, e.g. [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx).

> I get that you should make sure you Dispose an IDisposable, but why
> does it even implements IDisposable? what resources does it have to
> release? The only methods it has regard equality.

IMO, the best answer to this can be found in the [.NET 4 Cancellation Framework](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/net-4-cancellation-framework/) post by Microsoft's Mike Liddell:

> When a callback is registered to a `CancellationToken`, the current
> thread's `ExecutionContext` is captured so that the callback will be run
> with the the exact same security context . The capturing of the
> current thread's synchronization context is optional can be requested
> via an overload of `ct.Register()` if required. Callbacks are normally
> stored and then run when cancellation is requested, but if a callback
> is registered after cancellation has been requested, the callback will
> run immediately on the current thread, or via `Send()` on the current
> `SynchronizationContext` if applicable.
>
> When a callback is registered to a `CancellationToken`, the returned
> object is a `CancellationTokenRegistration`. This is a light struct type
> that is `IDiposable`, and disposing this registration object causes the
> callback to be deregistered. A guarantee is made that after the
> `Dispose()` method has returned, the registered callback is neither
> running nor will subsequently commence. A consequence of this is that
> `CancellationTokenRegistration.Dispose()` must block if the callback is
> currently executing. Hence, all registered callbacks should be fast
> and not block for any significant duration.

Another relevant document by Mike Liddell is ["Using Cancellation Support in .NET Framework 4" (UsingCancellationinNET4.pdf)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/UsingCancellationinNET4.pdf).

**Updated**, this is verifiable [here in the Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenRegistration.cs#2d80bf84f593cc0c).

It's also important to note, the cancellation callback is registered with the `CancellationTokenSource`, not with `CancellationToken`. So, if `CancellationTokenRegistration.Dispose()` is not correctly scoped, the registration will remain active for the lifetime of the parent `CancellationTokenSource` object. This may lead to an unexpected callback when the scope of the async operation is over, e.g.:

```
async Task TestAsync(WebClient wc, CancellationToken token)
{
    token.Register(() => wc.CancelAsync());
    await wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.hamster.com"));
}

// CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() may still get called later,
// in which case wc.CancelAsync() will be invoked too
```

Thus, it's important to scope the disposable `CancellationTokenRegistration` with `using` (or call `CancellationTokenRegistration.Dispose()` explicitly with `try/finally`).

Comment: Wouldn't the ExecutionContext also be captured in a "regular" lambda expression? and that doesn't need to be disposed...

Comment: @l3arnon, no it would not. The `ExecutionContext` is captured by the Framework only when there is a potential thread switch involved. It would be quite a big overhead if it was captured/restored for any "regular" lambda callback. More [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx).

Comment: Regarding the update, are you sure that's true? That the registration is linked to the CTS (through all its lifetime) and not just the CT?

Comment: @l3arnon, I am sure, and I find it logical: the cancellation is requested via the CTS, not via one of its tokens. If you need more details, check [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs#31a5196df8e4df6d) for `m_source.InternalRegister`.

Answer (score 4):

> why does it even implements IDisposable? what resources does it have to release?

`IDisposable` is often used for things completely unrelated to releasing resources; it's a convenient way to ensure something will be done at the end of a `using` block, even if an exception occurs. Some people (not me) argue that doing this is an abuse of the `Dispose` pattern.

In the case of `CancellationToken.Register`, the "something" is the unregistration of the callback.

<strike>Note that in the code you posted in your question, the use of a `using` block on the `CancellationTokenRegistration` is almost certainly a mistake: since `wc.DownloadStringAsync` returns immediately, the callback will be unregistered immediately, before the operation has a chance to be cancelled, so `wc.CancelAsync` will never be called, even if the `CancellationToken` is signaled. It would make sense if the call to `wc.DownloadStringAsync` was awaited, because in that case the end of the `using` block wouldn't be reached before the completion of `wc.DownloadStringAsync`.</strike> *(EDIT: not true anymore since the question was edited)*

> What happens if you don't Dispose of it? what do you leak?

In this case, what happens is that the callback is not unregistered. <strike>It probably doesn't really matter, because it's only referenced by the cancellation token, and since `CancellationToken` is a value type that is typically stored only on the stack, the reference will disappear when it goes out of scope. So it won't leak anything in most cases, but it might if you store the `CancellationToken` somewhere on the heap.</strike> *EDIT: actually, that's not correct; see Noseratio's answer for an explanation*

Comment: *"It probably doesn't really matter, because it's only referenced by the cancellation token... the reference will disappear when it goes out of scope"* - actually, the cancellation callback is registered with the `CancellationTokenSource`, so it will remain active when the `CancellationToken` is out of scope. This may be a problem later if the cancellation is still requested on the same source, [more details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21653382/1768303).