# C# Queue of Tasks

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, scheduled-tasks, async-await

I need to process tasks in sequence. So this class subscribed to some events.
When event is handled, asynchronous method must be added to Queue, and it might be executed when all previous tasks completed. At this moment it is realized as here:
But `ProccessTasks` method stops working when firs event is raised.

```
public class class view
{
    private void ModelUpdatedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        taskQueue.Enqueue(new Task(() => Invalidate()));
    }

    private void MoveCubesEventHandler(object sender, MoveCheckerEventArgs args)
    {
        taskQueue.Enqueue(new Task(() => MoveCube(args.Move)));
    }

    private async Task Invalidate()
    {
        //code here
    }

    public async Task MoveChecker(Move move)
    {                       
        //code here
    }

    private async Task ProccessTasks()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (taskQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                Task task = taskQueue.Dequeue();
                await task;
            }
        }
    }

    private async void UserControl_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => ProccessTasks());
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at BlockingCollection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ...or better yet, TPL DataFlow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx It worked nicely for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863573/awaitable-task-based-queue?rq=1

Comment: @spender So, i`m writing The app for Windows RT, it hasn`t System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow

Comment: According to the [NuGet listing](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow), Dataflow should be supported in .NET for Windows Store apps. Did you actually try to add it to your project using NuGet?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're never starting your tasks, ever.  You put unstarted tasks into the queue, and then you wait on the unstarted tasks when you pull them out.

Having said that, I would discourage you from just making that one small change.  Generally, dealing with unstarted tasks is fairly error prone, as you've seen.  I would suggest enqueing `Action` objects instead of `Task` objects.  When you pull the action out of the queue, you can then either execute it, or if you want to maintain asynchrony, use `Task.Run` to run it in another thread.

You also don't need to call `ProccessTasks` using `Task.Run`.  It's already asynchronous, so there's no need to run it in a background thread.