# How to enumerate an IEnumerable while another thread populates it

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I want two threads on the same machine, one that populates a collection and the other one that pops data out of it as soon as it's available and stops when it know it's over.
I just don't know what collection to use...

```
private void DataProviderThread()
{
    GlobalCollection = new SomeMagicCollection();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        GlobalCollection.Add(new SomeDataItem(i));
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    GlobalCollection.IHaveFinishedPopulatingThanksAndBye();
}

private void DataCruncherThread()
{
    foreach (var item in GlobalCollection)
    {
        // Do whatever
    }
    // The control should exit foreach only once the data provider states that the collection is finished  
}
```

I then want to iterate simply on it, having the Collection take care of

- Staying thread safe
- Grant the standard IEnumerable functionalities
- Let my data cruncher thread wait for new items until the DataBuilder has explicitely called `IHaveFinishedPopulatingThanksAndBye()`, then cleanly exit the loop
- Allow me to have several other threads iterating with the same constraints

I can't believe C# doesn't ship this in a new version. But what's its name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [awaitable Task based queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863573/awaitable-task-based-queue)

Comment: ConcurrentQueue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have is a classic Producer/Consumer pattern.

You can use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` or, probably better, a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The BoundedCapacity property lets you regulate (throttle) the dataflow.

It is an `IEnumerable<T>` but don't try to use it like non-shared collection. The `TryTake()` method is the most useful way to get your data.

Comment: Using it as an `IEnumerable` is a perfectly fine way to access the data, or if the situation warrants it, `GetConsumingEnumerable`.  I find that I very rarely ever need to use `Take` or TryTake`, given those two options, both of which are designed to be used while the collection is modified from other threads.

Comment: For some kinds of operations using the IEnumerable interface is OK, as long as you're aware of the concurrency. I don't find the ConsumingEnumerable very clear to use but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: You not thinking that it's clear is very different than it not working.  Both operations are very much designed to be used in a multithreaded context.