# Multiple producers single consumer locking schema

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have multiple producing threads, and single consuming. In C#, I'm using `ConcurrentQueue` for that.

How can I properly put the consumer thread to sleep, when the queue is empty?

```
ManualResetEventSlim signal;
void WorkerThread(CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        object work;
        if (!_eventQueue.TryDequeue(out work))
        {
            signal.Reset();
            signal.Wait(token);
            continue;
        }
        ...
    }
}
...
void Produce(object o)
{
    _eventQueue.Enqueue(o);
    signal.Set();
}
```

I tried this, but there is some chance, that

1. thread B fails to read from `_eventQueue`
2. thread A writes into `_eventQueue`
3. thread A sets the signal
4. thread B resets the signal
5. thread B waits indefinitely

How to overcome this? Previously, I used `lock()` and `Monitor.Wait()`. `AutoResetEvent` may help (it resets on successful `Wait`), but it does not support `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Why don't you use [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, frankly, haven't heard of it before. Looks like it does exactly what I need, if you post this as a answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: You can also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863573/awaitable-task-based-queue if you building server side code (like ASP.Net sites).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) class to support the case of multiple producers and single consumer.

Create an object of type `BlockingCollection` like this:

```
BlockingCollection<object> collection = new BlockingCollection<object>(); //You can have a specific type instead of object if you want
```

Producers can simple call the `Add` method to add an item to the collection like this:

```
collection.Add("value");
```

And the consumer can use the `GetConsumingEnumerable` method to get an `IEnumerable<T>` that takes items from the collection. Such enumerable will block (wait for more items) when there are no more items. This method also [supports cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395014(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
foreach (var item in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    //Consume item
}
```

If you call the [`CompleteAdding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086(v=vs.110).aspx) method, then the consuming enumerable will finish once there are no more items.

This class is completely thread-safe.