# Is there a C# class like Queue that implements IAsyncEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, queue, iasyncenumerable

Both `Queue` and `ConcurrentQueue` implement `IEnumerable` but not `IAsyncEnumerable`. Is there a standard class or class available on NuGet which implements `IAsyncEnumerable` such that, if the queue is empty, the result of `MoveNextAsync` does not complete until something next is added to the queue?

Comment: You could always find out for yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the .NET Core platform there are at least two built-in options:

1. The [`System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.BufferBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.bufferblock-1) class, part of the [TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) library. It doesn't implement the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` natively¹, but it exposes the awaitable `OutputAvailableAsync()` method, doing it trivial to implement a `ToAsyncEnumerable` extension method.
2. The [`System.Threading.Channels.Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) class, the core component of the [Channels](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Channels/) library. It exposes an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` implementation via its
   [`Reader.ReadAllAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync)² method.

Both classes are also available for .NET Framework, by installing a nuget package (different for each one).

An implementation of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` for `BufferBlock<T>`:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ToAsyncEnumerable<T>(
    this IReceivableSourceBlock<T> source,
    [EnumeratorCancellation]CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    while (await source.OutputAvailableAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        while (source.TryReceive(out T item))
        {
            yield return item;
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
    await source.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false); // Propagate possible exception
}
```

¹ <sub>Not available until .NET 5. Available from .NET 6 and later.</sub>
² <sub>Not available for .NET Framework, but easy to implement in a [similar way](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/ChannelReader.netcoreapp.cs).</sub>

---

**.NET 6 update**: This functionality is now natively available, with the extension method [`ReceiveAllAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.receiveallasync), with this signature:

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<TOutput> ReceiveAllAsync<TOutput> (
    this IReceivableSourceBlock<TOutput> source,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

There are two differences though between the new API `ReceiveAllAsync` ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/215b39abf947da7a40b0cb137eab4bceb24ad3e3/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Base/DataflowBlock.IAsyncEnumerable.cs#L17)), and the `ToAsyncEnumerable` shown above. The most important difference is that the exception of the `source` dataflow block is not propagated. So it's up to the consumer of the `ReceiveAllAsync` API to remember and `await` the `Completion` of the `source` after completing the enumeration, otherwise an exception will not be observed. A second difference is that the `ReceiveAllAsync` lacks the `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` line, so a cancellation signal is not guaranteed to have immediate effect. This behavior [is consistent with the behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67569758/channelreader-readallasynccancellationtoken-not-actually-cancelled-mid-iterati) of the `ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync` method, which [according to Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/56820#issuecomment-892662253) is "by design".