# Does ChannelReader<T>.ReadAllAsync throw any exceptions when being canceled by a CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, .net, system.threading.channels

Does `ChannelReader<T>.ReadAllAsync` throw any exceptions when being canceled by a CancellationToken? It doesn't seem to be throwing OperationCanceledException/TaskCanceledException?

I know if these two methods were called in a fire and forget manner, i.e. `_ = SendLoopAsync(); _ = ReceiveLoopAsync();`, it would've crashed the task with no displayed message/exception because they were not awaited, meaning that we're losing the exceptions.

I don't want it to crash that task without letting me know that it actually has crashed/been cancelled, which means I should probably wrap the whole SendLoopAsync in a try/catch instead of what's between ReadAllAsync's branches.

A small example representing its behavior will be appreciated.

```cs
var clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://www.deribit.com/ws/api/v2"), CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

var client = new ChannelWebSocket(clientWebSocket);

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    client.Output.TryWrite($"Item: {i}");
}

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
await client.StartAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false); // blocks the UI

Console.ReadLine();

public class ChannelExample
{
    private readonly WebSocket _webSocket;
    private readonly Channel<string> _input;
    private readonly Channel<string> _output;

    public ChannelExample(WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        _webSocket = webSocket ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(webSocket));

        _input = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
        {
            SingleWriter = true
        });

        _output = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
        {
            SingleReader = true
        });
    }

    public ChannelReader<string> Input => _input.Reader;
    public ChannelWriter<string> Output => _output.Writer;

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var receiving = ReceiveLoopAsync(cancellationToken);
        var sending = SendLoopAsync(cancellationToken);

        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(receiving, sending).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (completedTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception");
        }
    }

    private async Task SendLoopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await foreach (var message in _output.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending: {message}");
            await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    private async Task ReceiveLoopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var buffer = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent();

        while (_webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ValueWebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult;
            do
            {
                receiveResult = await _webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer.Memory, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    return;
                }
            } while (!receiveResult.EndOfMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: question: have you tried it? what happened?

Comment: @MarcGravell, No exception no anything. This is the only thing it returned `Sending: Item: 1`

Comment: Somewhat related: [ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync(CancellationToken) not actually cancelled mid-iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67569758/channelreader-readallasynccancellationtoken-not-actually-cancelled-mid-iterati)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that it *would* throw; of course, you can always test that, but - that is the general expected pattern in this scenario. So you would wrap it with a:

```cs
try
{
   // ...
}
catch (OperationCancelledException) when (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    // treat as completion; swallow
}
```

Alternatively: you could pass `CancellationToken.None` into the channel read API, and just use the writer's completion to signify exit (making sure that you call `.Complete(...)` on the writer when exiting).

That said: `ReadAllAsync` probably isn't the preferred API here, since you don't really *need* it as `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` - so it may be preferable to use the native channel API, i.e.

```cs
while (await _output.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationToken))
{
    while (_output.Reader.TryRead(out var message))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Good point.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias fair enough; that's a good catch (and a good `catch`)

Comment: I realized that I could also use `if (completedTask.IsCanceled) { }`, which comes from the Task.WhenAny.

Comment: Marc, is it possible to show me an example for `you could pass CancellationToken.None into the channel read API, and just use the writer's completion to signify exit (making sure that you call .Complete(...) on the writer when exiting).`? Thanks

Comment: @nop just use the last example, with `.WaitToReadAsync(CancellationToken.None)`, and use `_output.Writer.TryComplete()` when you're done

Comment: Thanks! One more question: since my whole code is async and it will be integrated in ASP.NET Core, is `_output.Reader.TryRead` an issue? Should I change it with ReadAsync (its async variant)?

Comment: @nop the combined `WaitToReadAsync` and `TryRead` is the recommended route - it avoids a few overheads when multiple items arrive at once, and it has a cleaner loop exit approach; the `ReadAsync` approach is the lazy/fallback route

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what does the `Task` returned by the `StartAsync` represent:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var receiving = ReceiveLoopAsync(cancellationToken);
    var sending = SendLoopAsync(cancellationToken);

    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(receiving, sending).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (completedTask.Exception != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception");
    }
}
```

It seems that it represents the completion of any of the `receiving` and `sending` tasks, which is weird. Most probably this is an unintended consequence of trying to log the exceptions of the tasks. There are better ways to log task exceptions than this, with the simplest being to enclose all the code inside the asynchronous method in a `try`/`catch` block. Beyond that, the [`Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception) property of a `Task` is not-null only when the task [`IsFaulted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted), not when it [`IsCanceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled).

Comment: Good point. I just realized what you wrote the hard way: "Beyond that, the Exception property of a Task is not-null only when the task IsFaulted, not when it IsCanceled"