# Task Queue with cancellation

Tags: c#, queue, task, cancellation-token

I'm looking for a way to be able to queue up a number of tasks to be completed in order, one after the other. But also for the functionality that when a new task is added, anything in the current queue is to be cancelled, and for the new task to **not** be started until any cancelled tasks are completed.

For example, if I queue task1 (that takes 5 seconds to do its work), and then 1 second later, I queue another task (task2), before task2 is started, task1 is cancelled and waited on until it "completes".

I came across the following code by Stephen Cleary which I have adapted to add the cancellation and was wondering if it was a good solution?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60992804/1520910

```
public sealed class ExecutionQueue
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Func<Task>> _queue = new BlockingCollection<Func<Task>>();
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationTokenSource;

    public ExecutionQueue() => Completion = Task.Run(() => ProcessQueueAsync());

    public Task Completion { get; }

    public void Complete() => _queue.CompleteAdding();

    private async Task ProcessQueueAsync()
    {
        foreach (var value in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            await value();
    }

    public Task Run(Func<CancellationToken, Task> lambda)
    {
        if (_cancellationTokenSource != null)
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        }

        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        _queue.Add(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await lambda(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                tcs.TrySetResult(null);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                tcs.TrySetCanceled(ex.CancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        }, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Example usage

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
     private ExecutionQueue _queue = new ExecutionQueue();

     public MainWindow()
     {
         DataContext = this;
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     int count = 0;

     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         int v = count++;

         _queue.Run(async (c) =>
         {
             try
             {
                 Debug.WriteLine($"{v} started");
                 await Task.Delay(3000, c);
                 Debug.WriteLine($"{v} completed");
             }
             catch (OperationCanceledException)
             {
                 Debug.WriteLine($"{v} cancelled");
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: ​Take a look at the `CancelableExecution` class in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource/61681938#61681938 "When to dispose CancellationTokenSource?"). It might be what you want.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that doesn't seem to be a queue?

Comment: No, the `CancelableExecution` is not a queue, but it behaves according to this question's description. The second `RunAsync` cancels and waits for the completion of the first `RunAsync`, in case the first is still running.

Comment: Ah I see, it does seem to do what I asked. Can I ask what benefits it has over the implementation I posted? (which seems simpler)

Comment: The `ExecutionQueue` by Stephen Cleary is not thread-safe. The `CancelableExecution` is thread-safe. The `RunAsync` can be safely invoked by multiple threads concurrently. Also it guarantees that the `CancellationTokenSource` is always disposed.

Comment: hmm, when you enable ```allowConcurrency``` it doesn't cancel the previous task. So multiple tasks run at the same time

Comment: Yes, this is the intended behavior of the `allowConcurrency: true`. In your case the desirable behavior requires that the `allowConcurrency` is `false` (the default).