# LongRunning Task behaviour

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, blockingcollection, long-running-task

I have a class that contains a `BlockingCollection<Task>` that is used to queue up a number of tasks to run in order (FIFO).

The queue itself is started on a separate long running task.

```
public class TaskQueue
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Task> _queue = new BlockingCollection<Task>();

    public TaskQueue()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ProcessQueue();
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    private async Task ProcessQueue()
    {
        foreach (var task in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            await task;
    }
    ...
}
```

When the application starts, I create many instances of `TaskQueue` as I need different queues for different components of the application.

The issue I am seeing is that even though `ProcessQueue()` is started on a LongRunning task `.NET Long Running Task`, after the first await of the task, it returns back on a `.NET ThreadPool Worker` i.e not a long running task anymore.

This results in all the instances of `TaskQueue.ProcessQueue` ending up on `.NET ThreadPool Workers` (after the first await), which then results in the application being very slow to start new tasks as it has reached the max number of concurrent running `.NET ThreadPool Workers` (I believe this is set to the number of cores the machine has, in my case 8), after which it will only create new `.NET ThreadPool Workers` every second or so.

So my questions are :

1. Is there a way to return back to a long running task?
2. Or should I just replace `Task.Factory.StartNew` with a new Thread? which I believe will solve the problem, but not sure if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to return back to a long running task?

Yes, by not leaving the long running task in the first place. You can change the signature of the `ProcessQueue` to return `void` instead of `Task` like this:

```
private void ProcessQueue()
{
    foreach (var task in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

This way the `LongRunning` task will alternate between waiting to consume a task, and waiting for the consumed task to complete. The same thread will do all the waiting.

Btw both the original `async` version of the `ProcessQueue`, as well as the suggested here `void` version, are doing nothing constructive. They are not processing anything, they are just waiting. I assume that you have omitted the "process" part of the method, to keep the example simple. Otherwise the `ProcessQueue` would be just an exercise to futility.

Comment: The ProcessQueue is there to ensure that only one task is executed at a time. The full code is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60992804/1520910

Comment: @wforl the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984105/queuing-asynchronous-task-in-c-sharp/60992804#60992804) by Stephen Cleary contains a `BlockingCollection<Func<Task>>`, not a `BlockingCollection<Task>`. Big difference.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was trying to simplify the question. But I assume I can still do as you say with  ```task().GetAwaiter().GetResult();``` ?

Comment: @wforl yes, the `taskFactory().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is a valid approach regardless. Ideally your `ThreadPool` should not be saturated, so you wouldn't have the need to use dedicated threads for just waiting (for the most part). You can configure the `ThreadPool` threshold above which it stops spawning immediately new threads to satisfy incoming work, with the [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) method.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that although the thread for the ProcessQueue is mostly just waiting, it's not a performance issue as the thread will yield? So it's not like it's using up additional CPU?

Comment: @wforl yes, this is correct. The dedicated thread doesn't cost CPU, it only costs memory (about [1MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656872/why-is-stack-size-in-c-sharp-exactly-1-mb)).