# Conditionally read from an asynchronous queue v2

Tags: c#

In programming languages there is a data structure called a FIFO queue.

I am trying to find out if there is an existing structure ( in .net or in a thirdparty library ) which offers the following functionality

1. FIFO queue
2. Aynchronous ( both read and write )
3. Blocking queue ( it will wait till you start writing to it, similar
       to BlockingCollection )
4. It will allow conditional reads. For example, every object added to
   this queue has a timestamp. You should be able to pop only those
       objects which are older than a certain timestamp, leaving the rest
       in the queue.

I am aware of the async collection discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863573/awaitable-task-based-queue) but it doesn't provide what I am looking for.

Comment: This isn't much different from your previous question earlier today which was closed https://stackoverflow.com/q/61490203/491907

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 you are right. I am hoping this question is clearer than the last one. At least it hasn't been closed yet :)