# Consume all messages in a System.Threading.Channels.Channel

Tags: c#, channel, producer-consumer, system.threading.channels

Suppose I have a *many producers, 1 consumer unbound Channel*, with a consumer:

```cs
await foreach (var message in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cts.Token))
{
    await consume(message);
}
```

The problem is that the `consume` function does some IO access and potentially some network access too, thus before 1 message is consumed many more may be produced. But since the IO resources can't be accessed concurently, I can't have many consumers, nor can I throw the `consume` function into a Task and forget it.

The `consume` function is such that it can be easily modified to take multiple messages and handle them all in a batch. So my question is if there's a way to make the consumer take **all** messages in the channel queue whenever it tries to access it, something like this:

```cs
while (true) {
    Message[] messages = await channel.Reader.TakeAll();
    await consumeAll(messages);
}
```

Edit: 1 option that I can come up with, is:

```cs
List<Message> messages = new();
await foreach (var message in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cts.Token))
{
    await consume(message);
    Message msg;
    while (channel.Reader.TryRead(out msg))
        messages.Add(msg);
    if (messages.Count > 0)
    {
        await consumeAll(messages);
        messages.Clear();
    }
}
```

But I feel like thare should be a better way to do this.

Comment: Looking at the docs... if you wait on a [`ReadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readasync?view=net-6.0), then, immediately after, repeatedly call [`TryRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.tryread?view=net-6.0) until it returns `false`, it will be equivalent to `TakeAll` or `Flush`, right?

Comment: Funny I just though of something simmilar. For now I'll wait to see if there's any better option. Perhaps I should use something other than `Channel` here.

Comment: [`System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.BufferBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.bufferblock-1?view=net-6.0) might be to your liking.

Comment: ...and a question I asked 11 years (!!!) ago... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863573/awaitable-task-based-queue

Comment: Is the [`Buffer`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Buffer.cs) operator, from the [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) package, helpful?

Comment: `BufferBlock` would probably work if `OutputAvailableAsync` was used before `TryReceiveAll` as it returns a `List<T>?`, exactly what I want. Though it's a bit unfortunate that `BufferBlock` is **several** times slower than `Channel` ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/)), so I am a bit reluctant to use it instead.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias From what I can see the `Buffer` implementation is as the name implies a buffer that keeps awaiting until a certain number of elements are gathered and yields them in a batch. It is an interesting concept, but ideally I want to consume the messages as soon as they come and only handle them in a batch if there happens to be more than 1 of them.

Comment: I see. How about this, a `Buffer` with a `TimeSpan` parameter, so that you can configure exactly how much time you want to wait before processing a batch? [Feature Request: Buffer with TimeSpan overload](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1679)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That would actually also be reasonable solution. Unfortunately, it's still in a feature request stage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After reading [Stephen Toub's primer on channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/), I had a stab at writing an extension method that should do what you need (It's been a while since I did any C#, so this was fun).

```
public static class ChannelReaderEx
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ReadBatchesAsync<T>(
        this ChannelReader<T> reader, 
        [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
    )
    {
        while (await reader.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            yield return reader.Flush().ToList();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Flush<T>(this ChannelReader<T> reader)
    {
        while (reader.TryRead(out T item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
await foreach (var batch in channel.Reader.ReadBatchesAsync())
{
    await ConsumeBatch(batch);
}
```

Comment: It's surprising how *simple* async code becomes with channels - once you get used to it

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly more polished version of the `ReadBatchesAsync` method in [spender's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70698445/11178549) answer. It features also an optional `maxSize` parameter, that can set an upper limit to the size of each batch:

```
/// <summary>
/// Consumes the items in the channel in batches. Each batch contains all
/// the items that are immediately available, up to a specified maximum number.
/// </summary>
public static IAsyncEnumerable<T[]> ReadBatchImmediateAsync<T>(
    this ChannelReader<T> source, int maxSize = -1)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    if (maxSize == -1) maxSize = Array.MaxLength;
    if (maxSize < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxSize));
    return Implementation();

    async IAsyncEnumerable<T[]> Implementation(
        [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        while (await source.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            List<T> buffer = new();
            while (buffer.Count < maxSize && source.TryRead(out T item))
                buffer.Add(item);
            if (buffer.Count > 0)
                yield return buffer.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
await foreach (Item[] batch in channel.Reader.ReadBatchImmediateAsync())
{
    await ConsumeBatch(batch);
}
```

Similarly to spender's answer, the above implementation is non-destructive. No elements that have been consumed from the `source` channel can be lost, neither in case of cancellation, nor in case of `break`ing out from the consuming `await foreach` loop.

A `CancellationToken` can be injected with the standard [`WithCancellation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskasyncenumerableextensions.withcancellation) operator.

The above implementation guarantees that each emitted `T[]` batch will contain at least one element, and at most `maxSize` elements.