# System.Collections.Queue<T>, threads, locking and synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking, queue

I have a `Queue<T>` field that is accessed by various threads. `Enequeue()` is called from multiple threads many times per second, while there is a **single** thread that performs the `Dequeue()` and `Count` operations.

I havent been thinking much about this until now, since I played it "safe" and used `lock` on a static object before any operations with this queue. While there currently aren't any performance issue, I would like to get rid of the locks if they are redundant. My questions are:

1. since I never iterate through the queue, are locks really needed in this situation? I mean, will the program crash when it happens that one thread enqueues and the second thread dequeues elements at *exactly* the same time?
2. should I perhaps use `Queue.Synchronized()` to get a wrapper, and if so: will that impact performance compared to the original queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: yes they are necessary; both enqueue and dequeue mutate state; a standard queue is not thread safe

2: [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) would work nicely; personally I use a version I wrote here on SO, [Creating a blocking Queue<T> in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228) - it makes it easy to throttle the size of the queue, and do efficient dequeues without looping

Note; with your current implementation the lock-object should only be static if the queue is static  (that isn't clear in the question, though) - otherwise all your similar queues may be sharing a lock

Comment: Thanks, `ConcurrentQueue<T>` appears to be working all the job for me, without the heavy locks.

Comment: @avance70 - unless you've profiled, I wouldn't automatically assume that the locks are "heavy" here...

Comment: I think my locks were pretty nicely implemented, affecting really only a few necessary rows. But, as you suggested `ConcurrentQueue<T>` I read somewhere that it uses `System.Threading.Interlocked` operations which are less expensive than the `lock`