# How to execute code on specified thread

Tags: c#, .net

What approaches do exist to execute some code on specified thread? So let's imagine I have a Thead and a delegate and I need to execute this delegate on this thread. How can I implement it?

I'm not interested in infrastructure things like SynchronizationContext, I want to know the ways to achieve this behavour manually.

Comment: Are you creating a new thread or do you mean that you somehow already have a thread that you want to retask to running this delegate?

Comment: @alun, I meant the case when thread already exists

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To execute something on a *specified* thread, you need that thread to pull the work, for example from a synchronized queue. This could be a delegate or a known type with some kind of `Execute()` method. In the case of UI frameworks, it is also usually possible to add work directly (or indirectly) to the main threads (via message queues) - for example, `Control.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

In the case of a delegate - a standard producer/consumer queue should work fine (as long as it is thread-safe). I use one based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228).

Answer (score 11):

If you just mean that you want to use the same thread for more than one action you could use a thread pulling from a blocking collection. Short demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<Tuple<bool, Action>>();
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var item = c.Take();
                if (!item.Item1) break;
                item.Item2();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting thread");
        });
        t.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to queue first action");
        Console.ReadKey();
        c.Add(Tuple.Create<bool, Action>(true, () => Console.WriteLine("Executing first action")));

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to queue second action");
        Console.ReadKey();
        c.Add(Tuple.Create<bool, Action>(true, () => Console.WriteLine("Executing second action")));

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the thread");
        Console.ReadKey();
        c.Add(Tuple.Create<bool, Action>(false, null));

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The thread will just block on Take until you queue an action up and then execute it and wait for the next one.

Comment: Check `GetConsumingEnumerable()` and the bool Tuple will be unnecessary.  The mainline code can simply call `CompleteAdding()`.  See _configurator_'s comment of [this blog post](http://www.codethinked.com/blockingcollection-and-iproducerconsumercollection).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx), at least if you are on .NET 4.