# How do I determine when all of my threads have finished executing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5, concurrency, notifications

I have an architecture that reads packets from a packetized binary file, assigns each packet to an individual processing pipeline based on the packet type, and reassembles the packets into a new file on the other side of the pipelines.  Each pipeline contains blocking queues similar to [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228)

There is a thread on each side of the blocking queue in each pipline that runs a loop that queues or dequeues packets.  These threads are started asynchronously (i.e. "fire and forget" style) from a controller object.  This controller object has a `Dictionary<int, ChannelPipeline>` collection that contains all of the pipeline objects.

Here's my question: *What mechanism can I put in place that will tell me when all of the pipelines have completed processing?*  There's an `EndOfData` property on each pipeline; do I have to continuously poll that property on every pipeline until they all read `true`, or is there a better (i.e. more efficient) way?

Comment: Make `EndOfData` an `AutoResetEvent` and `WaitHandle.WaitAll()` is your friend.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Unless he has more than 64 pipelines (or WaitHandles for that matter), [WaitAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx) doesn't seem to allow more handles to be waited on at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the total number of pipelines you can consider `AutoResetEvent` + integer counter

```
AutoResetEvent allThreadsDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);
int completedThreads;
int scheduledThreads;
```

basically each worker thread will increment it's value used `Interlocked.Increment()` and set event in case when it is last thread:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref completedThreads);
if (completedThreads == scheduledThreads)
{
    allThreadsDone.Set();
}
```

In monitoring thread you just do:

```
 allThreadsDone.WaitOne();
   // here is we know that all threads are finished
```

Comment: No, that only stops threads from completing.  A semaphore counts the wrong way.

Comment: @Hans Passant : Yep, I fixed that and basically removed an idea using Semaphore at all because not see way of handling that Semaphore is full/empty

Comment: Just to add, if you're using .NET 4.0, you can also use the [CountdownEvent class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235708.aspx), which seems to provide just that functionality.