# Parsing and reading with threading?

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, file-io, multithreading

I have a lot of files with a lot of size. They all need to be parsed and it takes quite long time. So, I came up with a idea: While one thread reads a file(harddisk's reading speed is the bottle-neck here), the other thread should parse the required information from lines and while parsing takes place, the file reading thread should go for the next file and so on.

I would just create two threads one reads all the files by File.ReadAllLines and the other thread parses the arrays returned. However this would consume so much of memory. Thus I need to limit number of files read to 5 for example.

Another problem I'm having is waiting for the obtaining-lines process to be completed. The parsing thread should know whether there is a ready to parse array.

The question is, what way should I follow? Is there an example of that(I couldn't find any)? Or is there a better idea?

Comment: What does the parsing code look like? What are you doing with the data you parse?

Comment: I am parsing variables by checking each line of a output file of a program. Not all the lines are read once. because if some conditions are met, I have to go back to nth line. I am obtaining each info to a variable and displaying them in DataGridViews.

Comment: Ok, perhaps you could post your sequential code so we have a better idea of what you are trying to do. Also, are some of the individual files very large, or could you read an entire file to a string array and process in memory, rather then reading line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure, that parsing is ALWAYS faster than reading, you can do it very simple:
Thread A (simply a thread to not block the UI-Thread) reads the file and then starts a new thread B and passes the file content to it (using Tasks instead of thread makes it easier). Put it into a loop and you are done.
Since the parsing is faster, the second thread/task will have finished before Thread A starts a new thread. So you will only have two threads running at the same time and 2 files in memory at the same time.

> waiting for the obtaining-lines process to be completed. The parsing thread should know whether there is a ready to parse array.

Not sure if I understand it correctly, but that would be solved by the above "solution". Because you always start a new thread/task, WHEN and only when the file has been read completely.

UPDATE: If processing is NOT (always) faster than reading, your could do it for example like this:

```
Private MaxTasks As Integer = 4

Private Async Sub ReadAndProcess(ByVal FileList As List(Of String))

    Dim ProcessTasks As New List(Of Task)

    For Each fi In FileList
        Dim tmp = fi
        Console.WriteLine("Reading {0}", tmp)
        Dim FileContent = Await Task.Run(Of Byte())(Function() As Byte()
                                                        Return File.ReadAllBytes(tmp)
                                                    End Function)
        If ProcessTasks.Count >= MaxTasks Then
            Console.WriteLine("I have to wait!")
            Dim NextReady = Await Task.WhenAny(ProcessTasks)
            ProcessTasks.Remove(NextReady)
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("I can start a new process-task!")
        ProcessTasks.Add(Task.Run(Sub()
                                      Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", tmp)
                                      Dim l As Long
                                      For Each b In FileContent
                                          l += b
                                      Next
                                      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
                                      Console.WriteLine("Done with {0}", tmp)
                                  End Sub))
    Next

    Await Task.WhenAll(ProcessTasks)

End Sub

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.Multiselect = True
    If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK AndAlso ofd.FileNames.Count >= 1 Then
        ReadAndProcess(ofd.FileNames.ToList)
    End If

End Sub
```

The idea (which as usually could be implemented in 4 dozen ways in .Net) is simply, that you schedule new processing tasks until you reach your self-set limit. If that is reached you "wait" until a task becomes ready and start a new one.

UPDATE2: With TPL lib it might look like:

```
Private Sub Doit()

    Dim ABProcess As New ActionBlock(Of Tuple(Of String, Byte()))(Sub(tp)
                                                                      Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", tp.Item1)
                                                                      Dim l As Long
                                                                      For Each el In tp.Item2
                                                                          l += el
                                                                      Next
                                                                      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                                                                      Console.WriteLine("Done with {0}", tp.Item1)
                                                                  End Sub, New ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, .BoundedCapacity = 4})

    Dim ABRead As New ActionBlock(Of String())(Async Sub(sarr)
                                                   For Each s In sarr
                                                       Console.WriteLine("Reading {0}", s)
                                                       Dim t = New Tuple(Of String, Byte())(s, File.ReadAllBytes(s))
                                                       Dim taken = Await ABProcess.SendAsync(t)
                                                       Console.WriteLine("Output taken = {0}", taken)
                                                   Next
                                                   Console.WriteLine("All reading done")
                                               End Sub)

    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.Multiselect = True
    If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ABRead.Post(ofd.FileNames)
    End If

End Sub
```

Which version is "nicer" ... might be personal taste ;) Personally I might prefer the "manual" version, because the new TPL Blocks are sometimes VERY blackboxish.

Comment: It is not certain that the parsing is faster.

Comment: @theGD: Updated my answer. Of course there a more than two ways to kill a cat.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar application and use BlockingCollection

[BlockingCollection Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In my case parse is faster than read but the problem I had was the files are not the same size so read could be waiting on parse.
With BlockingCollection a queue size of 8 managed the size variance and kept memory in check.
You could also set up parse to be parallel if parse is slower.
If you are reading from a single head then parallel read would not help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // A blocking collection that can hold no more than 5 items at a time.
    BlockingCollection<string[]> fileCollection = new BlockingCollection<string[]>(5);

    // Start one producer and one consumer.
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => NonBlockingConsumer(fileCollection));  // parse - can use parallel
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => NonBlockingProducer(fileCollection));  // read
}
```

What is the nature of the parse?
You are parsing one line at a time?
I would look at parallel parsing of lines before parallel parsing of files.
[Parallel.ForEach Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835497.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You *might* get an improvement in performance by splitting the tasks, depending on processing required.  The whole process sound similar to the producer/consumer setup.

You might want to check out [Blocking Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net) for queueing the processing.  The idea would be to have the reading thread queue items, and the processing thread(s) to dequeue and process items.