# Dictionary in MultiThreaded Application (memory management?)

Tags: c#, multithreading, pointers, memory-management, dictionary

I have a Dictionary that is `Dictionary<int, RSendPacket>` _Packets and there are two main threads. Thread #1 adding packets with this function

```
public void EnqueueOutgoingData(int id, byte[] data)
{
    RSendPacket packet = new RSendPacket(data);
    _Packets.Add(id, packet);
}
```

The Thread #2 is reads and sends the packet via socket like this

```
private void _Process(RSendPacket packet)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, RSendPacket> o in _Packets)
    {
        //Socket send (o.Value >> That's RSendPacket class)
    }
}
```

at this point, I'm getting an error. I'm adding "asdf" but it carries it as "►  o". It is a threading/memory error I think but I cant fix it because I don't know how! Can anybody help me about this? (I can implement a system in C++ with pointers and memory management and it should be a memory management problem -caused by my bad c#)

**EDIT1:** And yes there isn't a thread-safe implemention but I've tried it with 'lock()' and not works!

**EDIT2:** Oh another important edit. I'm using C# 2.0 with Unity. So solution should be a C# 2.0 (mono) code :/

Comment: Where do you see the "corrupted" value? In the `_Process` method? If you only queue and process a single packet does that work? (I'm thinking this would rule out multi-threading issues in determining the cause of the corruption.)

Comment: Also, at what point do you remove the sent packet from the `_Packets` collection? ... and is the `packet` passed in to `_Process` of any significance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution (I've tried and that works) is [l3arnon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21799615/2718774) but I'm going to implement this system in C# 2.0 and I've implemented it like [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net) with [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might want to use a queue for this kind of operation, it fits better what you are trying to do.

If you experience concurrency issues, you can use the ConcurrentQueue class.

Comment: It must be a dictionary because I need to find my values with a id key.

Comment: In your example you are iterating through the keyValuePairs and sending the value only - please update your code with relevant details about how you are using the dictionary to get better advice!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a lock to keep it thread safe. simply use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in place of the regular dictionary.

Comment: And it works but this is not the solution that I'm looking for because of C# 2.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not thread-safe, so behavior is undefined in your multi-threaded example.  Also, the order in which items are returned when iterating over a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is undefined, so you might not get what you expect even if you use a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` or implement your own locking.