# Dequeue from Queue with where expression

Tags: c#, queue, mutex, blockingqueue

I have a blocking queue class based on [Marc Gravell's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) [Blocking Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/530228/1959238)

Now I have situations where I want to dequeue only a certain object, I know this is not really the use case of a queue, but in some cases I think this is a good extension, for example waiting for a certain network answer.

This would be something like a

```
TryDequeueWhere(Func<T, bool> expression, out T value, int? waitTimeInMs = null)
```

The problem is I don't know how to wait and block for a certain object.

Comment: I'd recommend using `BlockingCollection` vs `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: What happens if you call `TryDequeueWhere`? Let's say the matching entry was at index 5. What would happen **exactly**? Would the entry at index 6 shift up to 5 (and so on)?

Comment: If an element matches the expression, the element is removed at the position, so the next element will shift up, right.

Comment: The short answer is that isn't a queue (as you already know). Could you build it? Sure. Basically you would need to lock the entire Queue, foreach over it until you find the matching element. If you find a match you will need to new up a completely new Queue (containing the elements before the match and those after it). Then unlock.

Answer (score 0):

After posting my code on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179993/69060) and improving by other users suggestions (thanks [Pieter Witvoet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51173/pieter-witvoet)) this is my final code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

public class BlockingQueue<T>: IDisposable
{

    /// <summary>   The queue based on a list, to extract from position and remove at position. </summary>
    private readonly List<QueueObject<T>> queue = new List<QueueObject<T>>();
    private bool _closing;


    private class QueueObject<T>
    {
        //// <summary>   Constructor. </summary>
        /// <param name="timeStamp">    The time stamp when the object is enqueued. </param>
        /// <param name="queuedObject"> The queued object. </param>
        public QueueObject(DateTime timeStamp, T queuedObject)
        {
            TimeStamp = timeStamp;
            QueuedObject = queuedObject;
        }

        /// <summary>   Gets or sets the queued object. </summary>
        /// <value> The queued object. </value>
        public T QueuedObject { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>   Gets or sets timestamp, when the object was enqueued. </summary>
        /// <value> The time stamp. </value>
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; private set; }
    }


    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            // Add an object with current time to the queue
            queue.Add(new QueueObject<T>(DateTime.Now, item));


            if (queue.Count >= 1)
            {
                // wake up any blocked dequeue
                Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>   Try dequeue an object that matches the passed expression. </summary>
    /// <param name="expression">   The expression that an object has to match. </param>
    /// <param name="value">        [out] The resulting object. </param>
    /// <param name="waitTimeInMs"> (Optional)  The time in ms to wait for the item to be returned. </param>
    /// <returns>   An object that matches the passed expression. </returns>
    public bool TryDequeueWhere(Func<T, bool> expression, out T value, int? waitTimeInMs = null)
    {
        // Save the current time to later calculate a new timeout, if an object is enqueued and does not match the expression.
        DateTime dequeueTime = DateTime.Now;
        lock (queue)
        {
            while (!_closing)
            {
                if (waitTimeInMs == null)
                {
                    while (queue.Count == 0)
                    {
                        if (_closing)
                        {
                            value = default(T);
                            return false;
                        }
                        Monitor.Wait(queue);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Releases the lock on queue and blocks the current thread until it reacquires the lock. 
                    // If the specified time-out interval elapses, the thread enters the ready queue.
                    if (!Monitor.Wait(queue, waitTimeInMs.Value))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        // select the object by the passed expression
                        var queuedObjects = queue.Select(q => q.QueuedObject).ToList();
                        // Convert the expression to a predicate to get the index of the item
                        Predicate<T> pred = expression.Invoke;
                        int indexOfQueuedObject = queuedObjects.FindIndex(pred);
                        // if item is found, get it and remove it from the list
                        if (indexOfQueuedObject >= 0)
                        {
                            value = queuedObjects.FirstOrDefault(expression);
                            queue.RemoveAt(indexOfQueuedObject);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    // If item was not found, calculate the remaining time and try again if time is not elapsed.
                    var elapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - dequeueTime).TotalMilliseconds;
                    if ((int) elapsedTime >= waitTimeInMs.Value)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    waitTimeInMs = waitTimeInMs.Value - (int) elapsedTime;
                }
            }
        }
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary> Close the queue and let finish all waiting threads. </summary>
    public void Close()
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            _closing = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged
    /// resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Close();
    }

}
```